# WPF .NET unable to add new instance to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and losing my mind with issues. I have a view, viewmodel and model. I want the user user to fill in some information in the view, press button to confirm and then have a new instance of the model (with the user specified parameters) added to the ObservableCollection and to my local database.

View: (unrelated stuff hidden)

```
<TextBox DataContext="{DynamicResource RiderequestViewModel}" Margin="15,0,15,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" Height="25" Text="{Binding Riderequest.Time}"/>


<TextBox DataContext="{DynamicResource RiderequestViewModel}" Margin="15,0,15,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="12" Height="25" Text="{Binding Riderequest.LocationFrom}"/>


<TextBox DataContext="{DynamicResource RiderequestViewModel}" Margin="15,0,15,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="12" Height="25" Text="{Binding Riderequest.LocationTo}"/>

<Button DataContext="{DynamicResource RiderequestViewModel}" x:Name="nextBtn" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" Content="Verder" Width="150" Foreground="White" Command="{Binding AddRiderequestCommand}" Click="NextBtn_Click"/>
```

ViewModel RiderequestViewModel:

```
namespace Drink_n_Drive.ViewModel
{
    class RiderequestViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        private Riderequest riderequest;
        private ObservableCollection<Riderequest> riderequests;


        public ObservableCollection<Riderequest> Riderequests
        {
            get
            {
                return riderequests;
            }
            set
            {
                riderequests= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Riderequest Riderequest 
        {
            get
            {
                return riderequest;
            }
            set
            {
                riderequest= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public ICommand AddRiderequestCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ChangeRiderequestCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteRiderequestCommand { get; set; }



        public RiderequestViewModel()
        {
            LoadRiderequests();    //load existing from DB
            LinkCommands();     //Link ICommands with BaseCommands
        }

        private void LoadRiderequests()
        {
            RiderequestDataService riderequestDS = new RiderequestDataService();
            Riderequests= new ObservableCollection<Riderequests>(riderequestDS .GetRiderequests());
        }

        private void LinkCommands()
        {
            AddRiderequestCommand = new BaseCommand(Add);
            ChangeRiderequestCommand = new BaseCommand(Update);
            DeleteRiderequestCommand = new BaseCommand(Delete);
        }

        private void Add() 
        {
            RiderequestDataService riderequestDS = new RitaanvraagDataService();
            riderequestDS.InsertRiderequest(riderequest);     //add single (new) instance to the DB
            LoadRiderequests();        //Reload ObservableCollection from DB
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (SelectedItem != null)
            {
                RiderequestDataService riderequestDS = new RiderequestDataService();
                riderequestDS.UpdateRiderequest(SelectedItem);
                LoadRiderequests();    //refresh
            }
        }

        private void Delete()
        {
            if (SelectedItem != null)
            {
                RiderequestDataService riderequestDS = new RiderequestDataService();
                riderequestDS.DeleteRiderequest(SelectedItem);
                LoadRiderequests();
            }
        }

        private Riderequest selectedItem;
        public Riderequest SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pressing the button simply does nothing and I don't know why. I also have a diffrent page where I want to show a datagrid of all instances in the ObservableCollection like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" DataContext="{DynamicResource RitaanvragenViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Ritaanvragen}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

But the grid just shows completly empty. I have added some dummydata to my DB but still doesn't work.

My appologies for the mix of English and Dutch in the code.

Comment: You explicitly set the `DataContext` for each of the `TextBoxes` but not for the `Button`. This means that they probably don't share the same `DataContext`.

Comment: I have updated the question and made a translated version of my code. I also added the DataContext to the button but to no avail.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the `Add()` method, does it get hit when you click the button?

Comment: Tried it, and apparently the Add() command does not get hit when pressing the button...

Comment: Then your binding doesn't work. How do you set the `DataContext`? Why do you try to set it for each individual control?

Comment: What do you mean exactly "with how do you set DataContext"? I have tried setting it on the outer grid and not on each element individually but that doesn't seem to help. However, VS is giving me a warning that the dynamicresource RiderequestViewModel could not be resolved. But I don't understand why not.

Comment: I mean exactly what I am saying. You should set the `DataContext` of the parent window or user control to an instance of your view model somwhere. Otherwise your bindings won't work. How is your window defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about it but i would do something like this:

As for first step I would change the TextBox to look like this:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{DynamicResource Ritaanvraag}" Margin="15,0,15,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" Height="25" Text="{Binding Path=Time, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

There's no need to pass your ViewModel to it as a DataSource because your View's first few meta-data related lines should already define what ViewModel does it belong to.

When you not specify the type of your binding, it will use a default binding type which depends on the current object. You're using a TextBox now so it will have a TwoWay binding by default.

If you only want to accept data from the user and you don't want to show the data if your model has any then you should use OneWayToSource. (Note: OneWay is a direction between source -> view.)

I would also remove the DataSource from your DataGrid because you already set it's ItemSource:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Ritaanvragen}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```